# Distinct with encapsulated equality

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of objects where I want to find distinct values based on several properties.

I could do this:

```
var distinct = myValues.GroupBy(p => new { A = p.P1, B = p.P2 });
```

But I want to encapsulate the equality sementics. Something like this:

```
public interface IKey<T>
{
    bool KeyEquals(T other);
}
public class MyClass : IKey<MyClass>
{
    public string P1 { get; set; }
    public string P2 { get; set; }
    public bool KeyEquals(MyClass other)
    {
        if(object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)
            return true;

        if(other == null)
            return false;

        return this.P1 == other.P1 && this.P2 == other.P2;
    }
}
```

Is there an O(N) way to get distinct values using my KeyEquals function?

Comment: why don't you just override Equals and GetHashCode methods ?

Comment: MyClass is mutable and I plan to use it in Hash collections

Comment: you can still implement an IEqualityComparer and pass it to GroupBY

Comment: Can you show an example? I don't want to get rid of the KeyEquals method.

Comment: @ConditionRacer If `MyClass` is mutable and the values that determine the hash are likely to change, then it's not suitable for a hash key - if the hash value changes your lookup would fail.

Comment: @DStanley Hence why I'm not overriding GetHashCode in the class. I have some class specific equality semantics which I want to use for distinct and groupby stuff (as well as other things). I'd also like a way to use it with Dictionary's and HashSet's, but I guess IEqualityComparer and GetHashCode are the only options.

Comment: I wish there was a hashset implementation that froze mutable members while they were a part of the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change `MyClass`, you can implement an `IEqualityComparer`:

```
class MyClassComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyClass>
{
    public bool Equals(MyClass m1, MyClass m2)
    {
        return m1.KeyEquals(m2);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyClass m)
    {
       return (m.P1.GetHashCode() *23 ) + (m.P2.GetHashCode() * 17);
    } 
}
```

And pass it to `GroupBy`

```
var distinct = myValues.GroupBy(p => p, new MyClassComparer());
```